# Eloquent Queries and Blade Display

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have my users table and a profile table with a user_id

in my `User` Model I have

```php
public function profiles()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Profile');
}
```

and the reverse in my `Profile` Model.

For my function to display on profile page I have

```php
$profiles = Profile::get()
    ->where('users', 'user_id', '=', 'profile.user_id');

return view('profile.profile')->with('profiles', $profile');
```

but I am not sure this is correct.  Trying to stay eloquent.  I also don't understand how to display the info from users and profile table on my profile page.  Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you tried using `join()`?

Comment: Yes and it collects when I dd($profiles) but not sure how to display on blade  For instance the name is on users table but the address is on profile table

Comment: In the blade file you can just use `@foreach($profiles as $profile)
 <p> {{ $profile->key }} </p> 
@endforeach`

Comment: The syntax you have is for a `join()`, not a `where()`, but you're chaining it after you execute the query via `get()`... You code should be `Profile::where('user_id', $someId)->first()` (if expecting 1 record, or `->get()` if expecting many), or simply `User::find($someUserId)->profiles`... The more I look at this question, the more wrong I see... `profiles()` suggests many (since it's plural), but `belongsTo()` only ever returns a single record or `null`...

Answer (score 1):

It may be as easy as this:

```
$profiles = $user->profiles;
return view('profile')->with('profiles', $profiles);
```

As long as you follow normal laravel naming conventions, which means that the users table is called `users` and has a primary key of `id` which is autoincrement. The profiles table is called `profiles` and has a FK called `user_id`.

If not, you may need:

```
    public function profiles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Profile", "user_id");
    }
```

Comment: It should be `$profiles = $user->profiles()->get();` or `$profiles = $user->profiles`.

Comment: @IGP - You are, of course, correct. So hard to write code without being able to run it.

Comment: Your code would have actually run fine with `$user->profiles()`, but it wouldn't have done much :P You had an un-executed query, which was still valid. Easy thing to overlook :)